# Visual Studio bug - Error writing the project file. Class not registered

Tags: visual-studio

I have just upgraded from Visual Web Developer Express 2008 to Visual Web Developer Express 2010. However, I can't use it. When I try to create a new project I get a small dialog box that says:

Error writing the project file. Class not registered.

[image]
<sub>(source: [yart.com.au](http://www.yart.com.au/stackoverflow/vwd2010.png))</sub>

I have tried reinstalling and repairing the product to no avail.

Answer (score 8):

The problem was MSXML6 was corrupt.

The answer is here:

http://www.ferolen.com/blog/error-install-ms-sql-server-express-in-windows-xp-sp3-msxml6-sp2/

But then I couldn't uninstall MSXML6 which led me to here:

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/microsoft-retires-windows-installer-cleanup-utility and [this download page](http://majorgeeks.com/downloadget.php?id=4459&file=15&evp=fe1c76da3437592326a3d668d72bf8f5)

Then I reinstalled MSXML6 from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=d21c292c-368b-4ce1-9dab-3e9827b70604&displaylang=en#filelist

and it worked.

Comment: Windows installer cleanup tool did not show MSXML in its list - I guess the problem for me was that MSXML was not installed. Once I installed MSXML from MS download center - the problem was gone.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the below site to know about ""Error writing the project file. class not register'"

http://technicalinformations.blogspot.in/2012/12/error-writing-project-file-class-not.html

Answer (score 0):

FYI, after installing MSXML6 and still error happens.
type this in Run Box.

```
regsvr32 msxml6.dll
```